# Why my Chrome freezes when I try to paste long texts?

Tags: ubuntu, google-chrome, vim, copy-paste

Every time I try to paste a long text that I copied from some applications (like Vim or using `xsel`) my Google Chrome freezes, after some time it responds again but the text is not pasted.

Around 60 lines is enough to make it hang. If I paste the text first in *Text Editor* and copy it from there, the paste in Chrome happens with no problem.

With short texts I have no problems.

This is happening on Ubuntu 18.04 and Google Chrome 75.0.3770

Using `xsel` I tried with the primary and the clipboard selection and neither of those works. What selection is *Text Editor* using then? Why does it work when copied from there?

Comment: Cannot reproduce. Maybe an extension problem? Try it in Incognito mode to disable all extensions.

Comment: @harrymc I tried disabling all the extensions but it kept happening. :/

Comment: Where did you get source text you select?

Comment: @VladGavriuk it happens with any long text on any textarea element of any web page.

Comment: @Dan have you tried to do same thing with other browsers? If yes, what are results?

Comment: @VladGavriuk in Firefox I have no problems, the same with other text editors. The issue is just with Chrome when the data has been pasted from certain applications.

Comment: @Dan what's the application you are pasting text from?

Answer (score 3):

I had this bug for many years, but now I've tried it on Ubuntu 19.10, Chromium 78 and it worked!

I could previously reproduce it e.g. on Ubuntu 18.04 Chromium 76.0.3809.87 with:

```
seq 10000 | xsel -b
```

and then I try to paste in an answer textarea here on Stack Exchange.

Here are two bug reports for the problem:

- https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=515401 The [comment 14](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=515401#c14) there says something about resolution.
- https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=473850

The problem does not happen on Firefox 68.0.1.

Comment: Apparently its fixed/closed ```Comment 14 by huangdarwin@chromium.org  on Thu, Oct 3, 2019, 8:45 PM GMT+2```

Comment: @Darragh thanks for this, I tried again and could not reproduce anymore, updated the answer.